# How to mix SQL data with OR condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL query to return 2 post_type between 1st January and 31th December :

`$url = current date (2017 for example)`

```
SELECT * 
FROM `posts` 
WHERE `post_date` 
BETWEEN '".$url."-01-01' 
AND '".$url."-12-31' 
AND post_status = 'publish' 
AND post_type = 'car' 
OR `post_date` 
BETWEEN '".$url."-01-01' 
AND '".$url."-12-31' 
AND post_status = 'publish' 
AND post_type = 'motorbike' 
ORDER BY 'post-date'"
```

My query works but the result reutnr `car` first and secondly `motorbike`.

I would like to mix data by `post_date` and not by `post_type` first.

Any idea ?

EDIT :

Current result :

```
Car | January
Car | February
Car | April
[...]
Car | July
Car | August
Motorbike | January
Motorbike | March
Motorbike | May
Motorbike | June
[...]
```

What i want :

```
Car | January
Motorbike | January
Car | February
Motorbike | March
Car | April
Motorbike | May
Motorbike | June
Motorbike | July
Car | August
[...]
```

Examples with 'month' but format date is 2017-12-31

Comment: can u show sample output

Comment: Just update your order by as `ORDER BY post_date`

Comment: The order by `post-date`  should do exactly that.  So the only way you get the 1st results you have is if the dates for all car posts are before all the dates for motorbike.  If that's the not the case.  Then give us some sample data/records so we can see the issue ourselves.  as it stands we can't recreate your problem.

Comment: did u tried order by both columns?

Comment: i think your posts are created in such as way that all first n records are **cars** and rest x records are **motorbikes** thats why u are getting cars first then motorbike event though u order records by order_date

Comment: If i am not wrong `'post-date'` this will be treated as a string literal not column so you need to order by your date column which is post_date not `'post-date'`

Comment: Order by post_date works, for example i'll have all car ordered by date and secondly all motorbikes ordered by date. Not easy to explain ! :)

Comment: This: `'post-date'"`  should be this: `post_date`  change the apostrophe's to back ticks and change the minus/hyphen`-` to a underscore`_`

Comment: @xQbert nothing change :'(

Comment: sql throws error if he uses variable other than columns.I think he used post_date only but here is mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DEMO: http://rextester.com/MBRS91171

Simplify query with an IN vs or

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts 
WHERE `post_date` 
BETWEEN '2017-01-01' 
  AND '2017-12-31' 
  AND post_status = 'publish' 
  AND post_type in ('car', 'motorbike')
ORDER BY post_date desc;
```

Or just make sure order by is syntax correct.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `posts` 
WHERE `post_date` 
BETWEEN '".$url."-01-01' 
AND '".$url."-12-31' 
AND post_status = 'publish' 
AND post_type = 'car' 
OR `post_date` 
BETWEEN '".$url."-01-01' 
AND '".$url."-12-31' 
AND post_status = 'publish' 
AND post_type = 'motorbike' 
ORDER BY `post_date`
```

make sure post_date is correct in order by `post_date` vs 'post-date'

Comment: nice idea, but they are not mixed ... i dont know why something so simple becomes so complicated

Comment: @reitrac  How are they not mixed? the Demo shows it mixing.  So you have something different than I do: either in data or in SQL.

Comment: I remove apostrophe's around and it works perfercly ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: +10. the most glaring issue with OP SQL is the expression in the ORDER BY clause. The single quotes evaluate to a string *literal*.

Comment: @spencer7593 yeah I can't believe I missed it initially. The color coding in SO was a dead giveaway.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are trying to do. But if you want to order by post type that are `car` first, then you can use `CASE` expression in order by like this:

```
...
ORDER BY CASE WHEN post_type = 'car' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 'post-date'
```

Comment: OP clearly mentioned *I would like to mix data by post_date and not by post_type first.*

Comment: This not solved my problem. Now, they are not ordered by date.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid based on what he said `but the result returns car first and secondly motorbike.` I assumed based that he wants to control the order.

Comment: @Reitrac what is your issue exactly? can you add some sample data and the desired output??

Comment: @MartinHoratio i just want to mix data by date :)

Comment: @Reitrac What do you mean by mix?

Comment: Mix mean ordered by date :)

Comment: @Reitrac - Still don't understand. In what logic this order by should based on? why 2 cars, then 1 motorbike, then 1 car, etc...? can you show the date as well

Comment: @MartinHoratio i added examples with month (but i use another date format, month was more simply to explain)

Comment: @Reitrac Thank you, but did you tried the query in my answer? it should give you the correct order.

Comment: @MartinHoratio i tried but my posts are not ordered by date but ordered by type. I need to mix type ordered by date.

Answer (score 0):

**How about this**

```
ORDER BY post_date asc,post_type asc
```

Comment: Same problem, data are not mixed (First Car and secondly Motorbike)

Comment: i think your posts are created in such as way that all first n records are cars and rest x records are motorbikes thats why u are getting cars first then motorbike even though u order records by **order_date**

Comment: @xQbert yes i tried with `post_date`and nothing change

Comment: Did you remove the apostrophe's around it?  back-ticks are fine apostrophe's are not. Demo: http://rextester.com/MBRS91171

Comment: @xQbert  can u show output of just post_date,post_type from table and please tell whether post_date is string/date type?

Comment: @krishnar It's not my question  Reitrac is the author.